# iphone: cross platform references and referencing external framework resources

Tags: iphone, image, resources, frameworks, external

working on an iphone app and separate framework.

the separate framework is for an API that i'm building for use in multiple future apps.

this api now needs to reference resources (images).  what i would like to do is keep the resources WITH the API framework as local set of resources.

i followed the instructions from http://www.clintharris.net/2009/iphone-app-shared-libraries/  to setup my app's project to use the headers from the separate API framework.

what i can't seem to figure out is how to automatically load the framework's resources into the app's xcode environment so they can be linked in at app compile time.

sure, i can drag the resources across from the framework into the main app's set of resources.  but that seems kinda ugly and another step that possibly can be automated (??) anyone know of a better way?  it would be great if any changes from the framework would be automatically available in the main app (due to the project 'link-age').

thanks for any help/tips/suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

You can't make your own frameworks and have the apps made with that framework get accepted into the iTunes store... Apple doesn't allow other frameworks in the App Store.